# UPDATING partial string from a field mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with columns like:

`emails`, `country_code` etc

Some of the rows contain emails like:

> XXXXX@googlemail.com

I want to change about 10,000 records like this in a way that will affect only the "googlemail.com" part of the value and change all of them to "gmail.com".

```
UPDATE exmple_table SET emails = REPLACE(emails, '%googlemail.com','%gmail.com');
```

I tried to find and replace but that making me have to type all 10,000 addresses in the query, any solutions?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 'but that making'. Would you not include a WHERE clause in your update statement to match on only rows with emails like <your criteria> ?

Comment: this isnt my issue, i am able to filter out the rows that i need, but is it possible to write a querry that will affect only the part of the string that is "googlemail.com"? and replace just that part with "gmail.com" and will leave the first part including the "@" intact. im basically trying to fix all the email address that have "googlemail.com" domains instead of "gmail.com"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'like' operator to filter out the records which contain 'googlemail' and then perform the string replace on them, as shown below:

```
update table
set SET emails = REPLACE(emails, 'googlemail.com','gmail.com')
where emails like '%googlemail.com%'
```

Comment: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 2652  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
that's what im getting in response :(

Comment: `select count(*) from table where emails like '%googlemail.com%'`.. How many records does this query return?

Comment: about 10,000 records

Comment: You also may need to uppercase the column and matching clause.

Comment: Also, take the % out of the Replace statement. It is attempting to match a literal on that.

Comment: tried, its not working. if i dont give the % than it tells me that it finds duplicate values and stops the querry

Comment: @AndrewMortimer thanks for the inputs, updated the answer :)

Comment: @DarshanMehta No problem :) Ben: Do you have a unique constraint on  'emails' ?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer its the primary key, thanks for the response guys!

Comment: If it's the primary key and I would suggest creating a temporary table, insert all the records into it with new values and then rename the tables rather than updating primary keys on the same table.

Comment: @DarshanMehta okay, so i created a new table like the one im using, but i didnt set the 'emails' to PK and it works, the only problem is that im left with lots of duplicates, how can i insert those new fixed values to my exsiting table without duplicating?

Comment: In this case, we may have corrupt/duplicate data. I would write a stored procedure like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344218/can-i-do-a-mysql-select-update-and-delete-in-one-query) and update only those records which won't cause duplicates.