# single query to group data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm saving data in MySQL database every 5 seconds and I want to group this data in an average of 5 minutes.

The select is this:

```
SELECT MIN(revision) as revrev, 
    AVG(temperature), 
    AVG(humidity) 
    FROM dht22_sens t 
    Group by revision div 500 
    ORDER BY `revrev` DESC
```

Is possible to save data with a single query possibly in the same table?

Comment: Check out `insert ... select ...` statement

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about reducing the number of rows, then I think you have to insert a new row with aggregated values and then delete the original, detailed rows. I don't know any single sql statement for inserting and deleting in one rush (cf also a similar answer [from symcbean at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4344426/2630032), who additionally suggests to pack these two statements into a procedure).

I'd suggest to add an extra column `aggregationLevel` and do two statements (with or without procedure):

```sql
insert into dht22_sens SELECT MIN(t.revision) as revision, 
    AVG(t.temperature) as temperature, 
    AVG(t.humidity) as humidity,
    500 as aggregationLevel
    FROM dht22_sens t
    WHERE t.aggregationLevel IS NULL;

delete from dht22_sens where aggregationLevel is null;
```

Comment: This is perfect, I add aggregatiolevel colum and I add where revision > NOW() - interval 1 day to aggregate only the "old" data.